# how to give color to datarow?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, datarow

I have created a datarow before binding the gridview.
this is my code :

```
DataTable dt1 = objAttendees.fetch_attendeesforSupplier();
if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();

    //DataRow dr = style.'background: #EEE9F8;';
    dr["CompanyName"] = Convert.ToString(dt1.Rows[0]["CompanyName"]);
    dr["keyfullname"] = Convert.ToString(dt1.Rows[0]["keyfullname"]);
    dr["Email"] = Convert.ToString(dt1.Rows[0]["Email"]);
    dr["attendeesfullname"] = Convert.ToString(dt1.Rows[0]["keyfullname"]);
    dr["attendeesemail"] = Convert.ToString(dt1.Rows[0]["Email"]);
    dr["CreatedDate"] = Convert.ToString(dt1.Rows[0]["CreatedDate"]);
    dr["TransactionType"] = Convert.ToString(dt1.Rows[0]["TransactionType"]);

    dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
    dt1.AcceptChanges();

    gdSupplier.DataSource = dt1;
    gdSupplier.DataBind();
}
```

Now I want to give a color to that `DataRow` only. How to do this in c# ?

Answer (score 2):

```
If(Condition True)
{
    e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant give color to `datarow`, however you can color to `GridRow` use `RowDataBound` of `GridView`

```
 protected void grdSupplier_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
{  



    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red;                
    }
}
```